The window resizing doesnot work properly
I have a MFC dialog based application. I want to change the size of the dialog to size in design units. I try to convert it to pixels, but it seems not to work. The ratio between design units a pixels changes after resizing - see notes in code.
This code I have in OnInitDialog():
RECT rect;
GetWindowRect(&rect);   //Window in dialog units has 300x200,, 466x364 in pixels
//I want to resize window to 200x100 in dialog units
RECT transRect{ 0,0,200,100 };
MapDialogRect(&transRect);
SetWindowPos(0, 0, 0, transRect.right, transRect.bottom, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER);
GetWindowRect(&rect); //here we are checking the size of window - it is not in accordance with my idea - the scale of previous and current sizes is not rigth
// it is - 300 x 163 in pixels, but I expect 310 x 182


The relationship between dialog units and pixels is not fixed, it's based on the dialog font size and some rounding.

Of course. And function MapDialogRect() should to transfer it.

You need to check what coordinates the respective functions need. Eg. Some expect "window/screen" coordinates and not dialog coordinates.

You could try to use the function MoveWindow instead
MoveWindow(0, 0, transRect.right, transRect.bottom, TRUE);


MoveWindow just calls SetWindowPos. That doesn't change anything.
